# Assembly calculator (sub & addition) with functions and arrays

Tags: assembly, binary, hex, calculator, x86-16

so I have to make a basic calculator(I'm having an exam tomorrow) but I'm stuck.
I'm getting first num to array,action(+ OR - ) and then the second number which goes also to array(number has to be 1-4 digits).
How do i take every digit from the array and convert it to full number(convert to binary), do the mathematic action and convert the answer to hex and print it?
It has to be done with separated functions and only when the user types 0 when the message to enter first num appears the program ends.
This is my code, hope you understand my question and code(couldn't find something similar to what I'm looking for on the internet).
thanks :)

```
data segment                                   
entr_first db 'Please enter first num 1-4 digits:',0ah,0dh,'$'
select_op db 'Please enter operation type + or -:',0ah,0dh,'$'
entr_sec db 'Please enter second num 1-4 digits:',0ah,0dh,'$'
ans db 'Your answer is: $'
num1 db 7 dup('5')
num2 db 7 dup('5')
answer db 8 dup('6')
opr db 1 dup('0')
data ends
sseg segment stack
sseg ends
code segment
assume cs:code,ds:data,ss:sseg
main:   mov ax,data
        mov ds,ax
        call kelet1
        call revah
        call keletOpr
        call revah
        call kelet2
        call dollar
        int 21h
        mov ax,4c00h
        int 21h
dollar:
        mov cx,0
        mov si,0
        mov cl,num1[si+1]
        add si,cx
        add si,2
        mov num1[si],'$'
        mov cx,0
        mov si,0
        mov cl,num1[si+1]
        add si,cx
        add si,2
        mov num2[si],'$'
        ret
revah:  mov ah,2
        mov dl,13
        int 21h
        mov dl,10
        int 21h
        ret
kelet1: mov dx,offset entr_first
        mov ah,9
        int 21h
        mov dx,offset num1
        mov ah,10
        int 21h
        ret
keletOpr:mov dx,offset select_op
         mov ah,9
         int 21h
         mov ah,1
         int 21h
         mov opr[0],al
         ret
kelet2: mov dx,offset entr_sec
        mov ah,9
        int 21h
        mov dx,offset num2
        mov ah,10
        int 21h
        ret
        code ends
        end main
```

Comment: Even SO is full of samples for converting string to number... Also be more specific what is causing you problem, do you need an algorithm or are you stuck implementing it? If so, where exactly? PS: comment your code especially if you want others to help. If this is a school assignment, revisit your learning material and consult your teacher.

Answer (score 0):

```
    mov dx,offset num1
    mov ah,10
    int 21h
```

This is wrong, service `ah=0Ah` of `int 21h` requires different data structure, see [documentation](http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah0a).

Also the input of second string is wrong of course.

And then after `call kelet2` the code stops making any sense.

(except `int 21h,ah=4Ch` exit call).

I don't think you can learn enough Assembly in 1 day to pass any Assembly exam from this starting point. So let's hope the exam is not about Assembly.

I think after 2-3 weeks of intensive (8-12h daily) study + programming you can get to "novice" level which would be probably enough to pass.

So what you are actually asking? This site is neither "code it for me" service, nor "free lectures of Assembly" (although in **limited** sense I tend to do exactly that here). Yet I can't supply half a year of missing effort in one answer.

Maybe you should move your exam into summer, and then work every weekend 4-6h on your Assembly knowledge.

Comment: I'm studying assembly for a year now and everything I wrote in my code is what we have learned and was told to write so

Comment: @ValerNaamaKuznetsov: well, what to say... 1) I don't see a way to "fix" you for exam "tomorrow" 2) after year this => something is wrong.. either your lector, or your effort, or your way of learning things or any combination of these. 3) if your comment is "but I **want**", and you will work hard for several weeks, then I may try to help by lecturing you a bit, but it's very time consuming, so make sure first your dedication is up to it and you actually do want to know to program in assembly. If I would tax my time by my normal rate (I don't), such course would cost like your whole edu bill.